# sass @import is not working for external files that starts with underscore

Tags: css, sass

The error is as below:
SassError: File to import is not found or unreadable: @library-x/core/style/main
from line 3 of ./styles/app.scss

contents of ./styles/app.scss

```
//more imports
@import 'variable'
@import '@library-x/core/style/main' //fails here
//more style definitions
```

folder structure

```
project root
---node_modules
------ @library-x
--------- core
------------ style
--------------- _main.scss
--- src
--- styles
------ app.scss
------ _variable.scss
```

If I change the import statement to @import '@library-x/core/style/_main' sass gets compiled perfectly.
On the order hand, the "@import 'variable'" works as expected.

Been scratching my head for this last few days, appreciate any help here. Thanks.

Comment: In your folder structure, the directory inside core is named styles, not style. In your import statement you reference a directory named style. Is that a typo, or is that the cause of your problem?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: If you change the `@import '@library-x/core/style/main'` line to `@import '~@library-x/core/style/main`, does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import path should be relative to the file that you're importing things to. So in app.scss you can reference _variable.scss with just the path `variable`, but for the _main.scss file, you would need to use the path `../../node_modules/@library-x/core/style/main`.

If your webpack is configured to look for modules inside node_modules, you can replace the "../../node_modules/" part with a single `~`. So the final path would look like `~@library-x/core/style/main`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does fix the importing of @library-x/core/style/main! unfortunately this library imports bootstrap/scss/functions by `@import "bootstrap/scss/functions"`. So its failing with `SassError: File to import is not found or unreadable: bootstrap/scss/functions`. I am not the owner of @library-x, so cannot change the import statement there. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: I believe it would make sense to post another question where you ask that. Off the top of my head, I'd say you need to add some sass-loader -specific configuration to your webpack that defines where the default importing-directories are. Or if the library you're using does not come with its own bootstrap, in a location where the import should work, you should notify the makers of the library about a bug in their import paths / a missing dependency.